# Missing parentheses around close vote count

Tags: feature-request, bug, mobile-web

The problem can be easily found while using the Android app and mobile web. Just find a question with a close vote on it and you will see this:

[image: screenshot-of-close]

> close 1

is what it says there. Can we fix it so we can have the parentheses around the close vote count so it can look like the way it is supposed to look?:

> close (1)

Comment: Is this perhaps intentional because there's less screen space on phones? (I dunno, just speculating)

Comment: pretty sure the mobile view does the same - which suggests it is not a bug, just a "feature"

Comment: @psubsee2003 it does, and having used the mobile app almost exclusively for months now, it still looks extremely silly

Comment: @raptortech97 not taking a position in one direction or another (doesn't really bother me), but making the point that it is probably a designed behavior, hence is not likely a bug.

Comment: Not relevant to android app, it doesn't show the pending close votes at all.